# How can I use additional icons in NavMenu in Blazor 8?

Tags: css, blazor, icons

I want to use additional icons in the `NavMenu.razor` in my Blazor **8** application. In Blazor 7 there was a iconset configured in `wwwroot/css/`, and so I was able to use additional icons only with naming it in the `NavMenu.razor`. But the whole css folder is missed in the Blazor 8 template.

There are only three icons configured in the `NavMenu.razor.css`, but I don't know how to add additional icons there.
I'm not a css expert. Is it possible to get new icons likely easily like in Blazor 7?

Comment: There are quite a few icon libraries available. For example, icons come with the MudBlazor component library. Bootstrap offer their own icon library. You can also install framework agnostic icon libraries such as FontAwesome by adding a client library to your Blazor app.

How you install and use icons in your app depends on which library you choose - there is no single answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is possible.
But be aware that this might increase your user's download considerably.

1. In App.razor, add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">`
2. In NavMenu.razor, remove (3x) the `-nav-menu` tail fom the icon names (ie, just `bi-house-door-fill`)
3. in NavMenu.razor.css, remove the 3 old incons.
4. in NavMenu.razor.css, in the `.bi` class, set `top: -0.75rem;`

That last one is a quick fix for aligning the icons, you may want to fine-tune that class a little better.

Comment: Great! And there are a lot more icons. But this way the icons seems a little bit small. Do you know how to change the size in the NavMenu? Sorry, I usually don't use css.

Comment: You can experiment with font-size in the .bi class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of Kurt I found a solution. I do not use the standard icons anymore, but the icons from a linked library, *Blazorise.Icons.FontAwesome* (https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/icons) in my case.
This way I changed a nav point in `NavMenu.razor`:

```html
<NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
    <Icon Name="IconName.Add" IconSize="IconSize.Large" />  @* new *@
    <span style="margin-right:0.8em;"></span> Counter  @* new *@
    @*<span class="bi bi-plus-square-fill-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter *@   @* old *@
</NavLink>
```

All possible icons are found even in the documentation.

I don't know how to use some more standard icons like the three from the template (that's why this response should not be the correct answer), but with an another library I can use more icons like demanded.